# Как записать имя пользователя, которое он вводит в переменную в callback функции?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота, который будет рассылать тз пользователям.
Использую инлайновые кнопки, для упрощения пользования ботом, но появилась проблема, что при работе кода ниже - в переменную записывается информация о самом боте, а мне нужно, чтобы бот дождался ввода ФИО пользователя и записал его в переменную

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def check_ready(call):
    if call.data == "ready_btn":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте, в данном этапе вам необходимо пройти техническое задание, в котором будет необходимо создать дизайн для карточек товаров.', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb2)
    if call.data == 'btn_no':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нажмите' + '<b>' + ' "Готов!" ' + '</b>' + ',когда будете готовы пройти регистрацию', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb)
    elif call.data == 'btn_yes':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Давайте познакомимся. Введите ваше ФИО (Иванов Иван Иванович).')
        user_name = call.message
```